# Why is sort function returning unexpected result?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, integer, max

When I am using sort function on a list in python, I am not getting the result I expect.
Like I tried to sort this list:

```
    numbers = ['4', '5', '29', '54', '4', '0', '-214', '542', '-64', '1', '-3', '6', '-6']
```

and after sorting, I get:

```
    ['-214', '-3', '-6', '-64', '0', '1', '29', '4', '4', '5', '54', '542', '6']
```

So here why is it printing 6>542 ??
I also used the max() function and it returns 6.

I have gotten the correct result by providing key=int in sort function, but why is it printing like this without the key?

Comment: It's sorting them as strings, because they are strings. Do `numbers = [int(num) for num in numbers]` before sorting to get the result you want

Comment: Because it's sorting them as *strings*, i.e. *lexicographically*.

Comment: When you use `key=int`, it calls the `int` function on each element before comparing them, so the elements are converted to integers and you get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of Strings, not ints so you need to tell the sort method to convert the Strings to ints prior to sorting.

For example, this should work:

```
numbers = ['4', '5', '29', '54', '4', '0', '-214', '542', '-64', '1', '-3', '6', '-6']
numbers.sort(key=int)
```

This should give you:
`['-214', '-64', '-6', '-3', '0', '1', '4', '4', '5', '6', '29', '54', '542']`